For stucco with tar paper & lath, is it ok to flash the window first and then wrap tar paper on top of it?
All information about proper window flashing I find online assume a house wrap and then they cut into the house wrap which wraps as the lowest layer around the sheathing (and sill/jambs). All flashing comes on top of the wrap.
But first, this assumes a house wrap and second, it assumes windows will come in after house wrap.
In my situation, I have stucco with lath & paper (remodel of a 1920 home). Also, my stucco contractor needed the windows to be flashed and sealed first. This also implies that I flashed my windows first to the structure. Then, the paper is then wrapped on top of it (and plan to seal it up with caulk before putting the trim and stucco).
This is how my window is flashed right now:

My stucco contractor will tie in new paper on the left (as good as he can since the 20s paper crumbles easily) and then put paper and lath on top of the Vycor rubber flashing.
(Note, per suggestion from How to create sill pan with a 1920s sill plate window? I will put a piece of wood under the window for better support and then caulk it carefully between window and sill)

are you putting in a metal backdam header flashing?

generally you start the window with house wrap starter strips.  you put on the metal header flashing ( on top of the top starter strip ).  You put the window in.  You put the building wrap on the house.  It goes on top of the metal header flashing and tapes to the window tyvek starter strips.  The bottom tyvek starter strip overlaps the building wrap.  I typically have my window sill framed with a positive drainage plane which then gets either blueskin or flexwrap that overlaps the lower starter strip which is fastened to the overall building wrap last.  Lots of details !

You really have no choice. Flashing tape isn't intended to bond to felt. It's not a reliable connection. Therefore, you ideally want the layering to be conducive to outward water flow, with the felt lapping the flashing tape on top and vice-versa below.
It's always a tricky situation when you're retrofitting. The devil's in the details, such as getting good lap with new and old felt. That's where the real risk lies.

Just to double check, with “felt” you mean the tar paper and you’re saying, first sealing & flashing the windows and then putting the the tar paper on top is fine (“I have no choice”)? Of course with proper layering and particularly at the bottom where (additional) rubber flashing must be on top of the paper for proper water shedding

Honestly at this point 4 windows are done and I don’t think there’s an easy way back anyway. It does look good to me (https://imgur.com/a/BhK8wZP) but if I interpret your answer the right way it gives me peace of mind
